# Null array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, userscripts

everyone. I wrote a userscript about a year ago that changes the colors of badge borders on kongregate.com based upon the difficulty of the badge. They have since added new features, and now the script is broken.

The error that's being thrown in the console is at the line of the first conditional of the `changeBorders(span, difficultyText)` function: "difficultyText is undefined". I went back to my function call `changeBorders(border, badges[src]);`, and am puzzled as to why badges[src]  is not working as it used to.

From what I understand, badges is a multi-dimensional array that stores the URL of the image (assigned in second `for` loop) and it's corresponding difficulty (assigned in first `for` loop) as a value pair. I am stumped as to where to go from here.

**The Code**: http://pastebin.com/K9Cr6HiE

**Test Page**: http://www.kongregate.com/badges

Could someone help me find where my `difficultyText` assignment is failing?

EDIT: [Here's where the userscript can be found](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/60378).

Comment: First thing I advise is to get in there and make sure that **all** your local variables are correctly declared with **`var`**

Comment: Is this the complete script?  Does it just change the borders?  It seems somewhat convoluted for just that.  Why is it using an array of `badges` by image source?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to figure out that code versus what changed, I ended up refactoring it in accordance with [DRY principles](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)

The following tested OK on Firefox; should work on Chrome too:

```
setTimeout (SwitchOnPageType, 0);


function SwitchOnPageType ()
{
    //--- Is this an accounts or a badges page?  Or neither?
    var path        = location.pathname;
    var pathArray   = path.split("/");

    if(pathArray[1] == "accounts")
        badgeSetup (true);

    else if(pathArray[1].indexOf("badges") != -1 | pathArray[1].indexOf("badge_quests") != -1)
        badgeSetup (false);
}


function badgeSetup (bIsAccountsPage)
{
    if (bIsAccountsPage)
        var badgeImages     = document.querySelectorAll ("div.badge_list div.badge_image");
    else
        var badgeImages     = document.querySelectorAll ("div.badge_image");

    for (var J = badgeImages.length-1;  J >= 0;  --J)
    {
        if (bIsAccountsPage)
        {
            //--- In this page type, the ID of the node we want is given in a mouseover attribute.
            var elemWithTextId  = badgeImages[J].innerHTML.replace (/(?:.|\n)+(userbadges-\d+_details)(?:.|\n)+/i, "$1");
            var elemWithText    = document.querySelector ('#' + elemWithTextId + ' span.badge_name');
            var difficultyText  = elemWithText.innerHTML;
        }
        else
            var difficultyText  = badgeImages[J].parentNode.parentNode.title;

        var borderElem  = badgeImages[J].parentNode.querySelector ("div.badge_border span");

        changeBorder (borderElem, difficultyText);
    }
}


function changeBorder (borderElement, difficultyText)
{
    /*  TO CHANGE A BORDER IMAGE, DELETE THE ENTIRE "data:image" SECTION AND REPLACE
        IT WITH THE URL OF YOUR IMAGE IN QUOTATION MARKS.
        Example:  "http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v179/Aironi/badge_earned_red_final.png"
    */
    var srchTxtArry     = [ "easy\\s+-\\s+5\\s+points",
                            "medium\\s+-\\s+15\\s+points",
                            "hard\\s+-\\s+30\\s+points",
                            "impossible\\s+-\\s+60\\s+points"
                        ];
    var badgeBorderArry = [ "http://www.kingcards.com/images/missu/thm/sadpup_bf8.gif",
                            "data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%2C%00%00%00%2C%08%06%00%00%00%1E%84Z%01%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%12%00%00%0B%12%01%D2%DD~%FC%00%00%0AOiCCPPhotoshop%20ICC%20profile%00%00x%DA%9DSgTS%E9%16%3D%F7%DE%F4BK%88%80%94KoR%15%08%20RB%8B%80%14%91%26*!%09%10J%88!%A1%D9%15Q%C1%11EE%04%1B%C8%A0%88%03%8E%8E%80%8C%15Q%2C%0C%8A%0A%D8%07%E4!%A2%8E%83%A3%88%8A%CA%FB%E1%7B%A3k%D6%BC%F7%E6%CD%FE%B5%D7%3E%E7%AC%F3%9D%B3%CF%07%C0%08%0C%96H3Q5%80%0C%A9B%1E%11%E0%83%C7%C4%C6%E1%E4.%40%81%0A%24p%00%10%08%B3d!s%FD%23%01%00%F8~%3C%3C%2B%22%C0%07%BE%00%01x%D3%0B%08%00%C0M%9B%C00%1C%87%FF%0F%EAB%99%5C%01%80%84%01%C0t%918K%08%80%14%00%40z%8EB%A6%00%40F%01%80%9D%98%26S%00%A0%04%00%60%CBcb%E3%00P-%00%60'%7F%E6%D3%00%80%9D%F8%99%7B%01%00%5B%94!%15%01%A0%91%00%20%13e%88D%00h%3B%00%AC%CFV%8AE%00X0%00%14fK%C49%00%D8-%000IWfH%00%B0%B7%00%C0%CE%10%0B%B2%00%08%0C%000Q%88%85)%00%04%7B%00%60%C8%23%23x%00%84%99%00%14F%F2W%3C%F1%2B%AE%10%E7*%00%00x%99%B2%3C%B9%249E%81%5B%08-q%07WW.%1E(%CEI%17%2B%146a%02a%9A%40.%C2y%99%192%814%0F%E0%F3%CC%00%00%A0%91%15%11%E0%83%F3%FDx%CE%0E%AE%CE%CE6%8E%B6%0E_-%EA%BF%06%FF%22bb%E3%FE%E5%CF%ABp%40%00%00%E1t~%D1%FE%2C%2F%B3%1A%80%3B%06%80m%FE%A2%25%EE%04h%5E%0B%A0u%F7%8Bf%B2%0F%40%B5%00%A0%E9%DAW%F3p%F8~%3C%3CE%A1%90%B9%D9%D9%E5%E4%E4%D8J%C4B%5Ba%CAW%7D%FEg%C2_%C0W%FDl%F9~%3C%FC%F7%F5%E0%BE%E2%24%812%5D%81G%04%F8%E0%C2%CC%F4L%A5%1C%CF%92%09%84b%DC%E6%8FG%FC%B7%0B%FF%FC%1D%D3%22%C4Ib%B9X*%14%E3Q%12q%8ED%9A%8C%F32%A5%22%89B%92)%C5%25%D2%FFd%E2%DF%2C%FB%03%3E%DF5%00%B0j%3E%01%7B%91-%A8%5Dc%03%F6K'%10Xt%C0%E2%F7%00%00%F2%BBo%C1%D4(%08%03%80h%83%E1%CFw%FF%EF%3F%FDG%A0%25%00%80fI%92q%00%00%5ED%24.T%CA%B3%3F%C7%08%00%00D%A0%81*%B0A%1B%F4%C1%18%2C%C0%06%1C%C1%05%DC%C1%0B%FC%606%84B%24%C4%C2B%10B%0Ad%80%1Cr%60)%AC%82B(%86%CD%B0%1D*%60%2F%D4%40%1D4%C0Qh%86%93p%0E.%C2U%B8%0E%3Dp%0F%FAa%08%9E%C1(%BC%81%09%04A%C8%08%13a!%DA%88%01b%8AX%23%8E%08%17%99%85%F8!%C1H%04%12%8B%24%20%C9%88%14Q%22K%915H1R%8AT%20UH%1D%F2%3Dr%029%87%5CF%BA%91%3B%C8%002%82%FC%86%BCG1%94%81%B2Q%3D%D4%0C%B5C%B9%A87%1A%84F%A2%0B%D0dt1%9A%8F%16%A0%9B%D0r%B4%1A%3D%8C6%A1%E7%D0%ABh%0F%DA%8F%3EC%C70%C0%E8%18%073%C4l0.%C6%C3B%B18%2C%09%93c%CB%B1%22%AC%0C%AB%C6%1A%B0V%AC%03%BB%89%F5c%CF%B1w%04%12%81E%C0%096%04wB%20a%1EAHXLXN%D8H%A8%20%1C%244%11%DA%097%09%03%84Q%C2'%22%93%A8K%B4%26%BA%11%F9%C4%18b21%87XH%2C%23%D6%12%8F%13%2F%10%7B%88C%C47%24%12%89C2'%B9%90%02I%B1%A4T%D2%12%D2F%D2nR%23%E9%2C%A9%9B4H%1A%23%93%C9%DAdk%B2%079%94%2C%20%2B%C8%85%E4%9D%E4%C3%E43%E4%1B%E4!%F2%5B%0A%9Db%40q%A4%F8S%E2(R%CAjJ%19%E5%10%E54%E5%06e%982AU%A3%9AR%DD%A8%A1T%115%8FZB%AD%A1%B6R%AFQ%87%A8%134u%9A9%CD%83%16IK%A5%AD%A2%95%D3%1Ah%17h%F7i%AF%E8t%BA%11%DD%95%1EN%97%D0W%D2%CB%E9G%E8%97%E8%03%F4w%0C%0D%86%15%83%C7%88g(%19%9B%18%07%18g%19w%18%AF%98L%A6%19%D3%8B%19%C7T071%EB%98%E7%99%0F%99oUX*%B6*%7C%15%91%CA%0A%95J%95%26%95%1B*%2FT%A9%AA%A6%AA%DE%AA%0BU%F3U%CBT%8F%A9%5ES%7D%AEFU3S%E3%A9%09%D4%96%ABU%AA%9DP%EBS%1BSg%A9%3B%A8%87%AAg%A8oT%3F%A4~Y%FD%89%06Y%C3L%C3OC%A4Q%A0%B1_%E3%BC%C6%20%0Bc%19%B3x%2C!k%0D%AB%86u%815%C4%26%B1%CD%D9%7Cv*%BB%98%FD%1D%BB%8B%3D%AA%A9%A19C3J3W%B3R%F3%94f%3F%07%E3%98q%F8%9CtN%09%E7(%A7%97%F3~%8A%DE%14%EF)%E2)%1B%A64L%B91e%5Ck%AA%96%97%96X%ABH%ABQ%ABG%EB%BD6%AE%ED%A7%9D%A6%BDE%BBY%FB%81%0EA%C7J'%5C'Gg%8F%CE%05%9D%E7S%D9S%DD%A7%0A%A7%16M%3D%3A%F5%AE.%AAk%A5%1B%A1%BBDw%BFn%A7%EE%98%9E%BE%5E%80%9ELo%A7%DEy%BD%E7%FA%1C%7D%2F%FDT%FDm%FA%A7%F5G%0CX%06%B3%0C%24%06%DB%0C%CE%18%3C%C55qo%3C%1D%2F%C7%DB%F1QC%5D%C3%40C%A5a%95a%97%E1%84%91%B9%D1%3C%A3%D5F%8DF%0F%8Ci%C6%5C%E3%24%E3m%C6m%C6%A3%26%06%26!%26KM%EAM%EE%9ARM%B9%A6)%A6%3BL%3BL%C7%CD%CC%CD%A2%CD%D6%995%9B%3D1%D72%E7%9B%E7%9B%D7%9B%DF%B7%60ZxZ%2C%B6%A8%B6%B8eI%B2%E4Z%A6Y%EE%B6%BCn%85Z9Y%A5XUZ%5D%B3F%AD%9D%AD%25%D6%BB%AD%BB%A7%11%A7%B9N%93N%AB%9E%D6g%C3%B0%F1%B6%C9%B6%A9%B7%19%B0%E5%D8%06%DB%AE%B6m%B6%7Dagb%17g%B7%C5%AE%C3%EE%93%BD%93%7D%BA%7D%8D%FD%3D%07%0D%87%D9%0E%AB%1DZ%1D~s%B4r%14%3AV%3A%DE%9A%CE%9C%EE%3F%7D%C5%F4%96%E9%2FgX%CF%10%CF%D83%E3%B6%13%CB)%C4i%9DS%9B%D3Gg%17g%B9s%83%F3%88%8B%89K%82%CB.%97%3E.%9B%1B%C6%DD%C8%BD%E4Jt%F5q%5D%E1z%D2%F5%9D%9B%B3%9B%C2%ED%A8%DB%AF%EE6%EEi%EE%87%DC%9F%CC4%9F)%9EY3s%D0%C3%C8C%E0Q%E5%D1%3F%0B%9F%950k%DF%AC~OCO%81g%B5%E7%23%2Fc%2F%91W%AD%D7%B0%B7%A5w%AA%F7a%EF%17%3E%F6%3Er%9F%E3%3E%E3%3C7%DE2%DEY_%CC7%C0%B7%C8%B7%CBO%C3o%9E_%85%DFC%7F%23%FFd%FFz%FF%D1%00%A7%80%25%01g%03%89%81A%81%5B%02%FB%F8z%7C!%BF%8E%3F%3A%DBe%F6%B2%D9%EDA%8C%A0%B9A%15A%8F%82%AD%82%E5%C1%AD!h%C8%EC%90%AD!%F7%E7%98%CE%91%CEi%0E%85P~%E8%D6%D0%07a%E6a%8B%C3~%0C'%85%87%85W%86%3F%8Ep%88X%1A%D11%975w%D1%DCCs%DFD%FAD%96D%DE%9Bg1O9%AF-J5*%3E%AA.j%3C%DA7%BA4%BA%3F%C6.fY%CC%D5X%9DXIlK%1C9.*%AE6nl%BE%DF%FC%ED%F3%87%E2%9D%E2%0B%E3%7B%17%98%2F%C8%5Dpy%A1%CE%C2%F4%85%A7%16%A9.%12%2C%3A%96%40L%88N8%94%F0A%10*%A8%16%8C%25%F2%13w%25%8E%0Ay%C2%1D%C2g%22%2F%D16%D1%88%D8C%5C*%1EN%F2H*Mz%92%EC%91%BC5y%24%C53%A5%2C%E5%B9%84'%A9%90%BCL%0DL%DD%9B%3A%9E%16%9Av%20m2%3D%3A%BD1%83%92%91%90qB%AA!M%93%B6g%EAg%E6fv%CB%ACe%85%B2%FE%C5n%8B%B7%2F%1E%95%07%C9k%B3%90%AC%05Y-%0A%B6B%A6%E8TZ(%D7*%07%B2geWf%BF%CD%89%CA9%96%AB%9E%2B%CD%ED%CC%B3%CA%DB%907%9C%EF%9F%FF%ED%12%C2%12%E1%92%B6%A5%86KW-%1DX%E6%BD%ACj9%B2%3Cqy%DB%0A%E3%15%05%2B%86V%06%AC%3C%B8%8A%B6*m%D5O%AB%EDW%97%AE~%BD%26zMk%81%5E%C1%CA%82%C1%B5%01k%EB%0BU%0A%E5%85%7D%EB%DC%D7%ED%5DOX%2FY%DF%B5a%FA%86%9D%1B%3E%15%89%8A%AE%14%DB%17%97%15%7F%D8(%DCx%E5%1B%87o%CA%BF%99%DC%94%B4%A9%AB%C4%B9d%CFf%D2f%E9%E6%DE-%9E%5B%0E%96%AA%97%E6%97%0En%0D%D9%DA%B4%0D%DFV%B4%ED%F5%F6E%DB%2F%97%CD(%DB%BB%83%B6C%B9%A3%BF%3C%B8%BCe%A7%C9%CE%CD%3B%3FT%A4T%F4T%FAT6%EE%D2%DD%B5a%D7%F8n%D1%EE%1B%7B%BC%F64%EC%D5%DB%5B%BC%F7%FD%3E%C9%BE%DBU%01UM%D5f%D5e%FBI%FB%B3%F7%3F%AE%89%AA%E9%F8%96%FBm%5D%ADNmq%ED%C7%03%D2%03%FD%07%23%0E%B6%D7%B9%D4%D5%1D%D2%3DTR%8F%D6%2B%EBG%0E%C7%1F%BE%FE%9D%EFw-%0D6%0DU%8D%9C%C6%E2%23pDy%E4%E9%F7%09%DF%F7%1E%0D%3A%DAv%8C%7B%AC%E1%07%D3%1Fv%1Dg%1D%2FjB%9A%F2%9AF%9BS%9A%FB%5Bb%5B%BAO%CC%3E%D1%D6%EA%DEz%FCG%DB%1F%0F%9C4%3CYyJ%F3T%C9i%DA%E9%82%D3%93g%F2%CF%8C%9D%95%9D%7D~.%F9%DC%60%DB%A2%B6%7B%E7c%CE%DFj%0Fo%EF%BA%10t%E1%D2E%FF%8B%E7%3B%BC%3B%CE%5C%F2%B8t%F2%B2%DB%E5%13W%B8W%9A%AF%3A_m%EAt%EA%3C%FE%93%D3O%C7%BB%9C%BB%9A%AE%B9%5Ck%B9%EEz%BD%B5%7Bf%F7%E9%1B%9E7%CE%DD%F4%BDy%F1%16%FF%D6%D5%9E9%3D%DD%BD%F3zo%F7%C5%F7%F5%DF%16%DD~r'%FD%CE%CB%BB%D9w'%EE%AD%BCO%BC_%F4%40%EDA%D9C%DD%87%D5%3F%5B%FE%DC%D8%EF%DC%7Fj%C0w%A0%F3%D1%DCG%F7%06%85%83%CF%FE%91%F5%8F%0FC%05%8F%99%8F%CB%86%0D%86%EB%9E8%3E99%E2%3Fr%FD%E9%FC%A7C%CFd%CF%26%9E%17%FE%A2%FE%CB%AE%17%16%2F~%F8%D5%EB%D7%CE%D1%98%D1%A1%97%F2%97%93%BFm%7C%A5%FD%EA%C0%EB%19%AF%DB%C6%C2%C6%1E%BE%C9x31%5E%F4V%FB%ED%C1w%DCw%1D%EF%A3%DF%0FO%E4%7C%20%7F(%FFh%F9%B1%F5S%D0%A7%FB%93%19%93%93%FF%04%03%98%F3%FCc3-%DB%00%00%00%20cHRM%00%00z%25%00%00%80%83%00%00%F9%FF%00%00%80%E9%00%00u0%00%00%EA%60%00%00%3A%98%00%00%17o%92_%C5F%00%00%02%1BIDATx%DA%EC%D91h%13Q%18%07%F0%FF%BB%D4%06%C3%25%1C%C4%D1%40gyqIJ%14%04%AB%A2%AE%92%22%96b%8BY%5C%5CtT%A1%B6%15%E9%EA%A4%EB%89(%C5%10D'%83%82%83%93%90%0E%F2%3Eqq%AA%20%A2%04c%7CV%0F%9B~.%8D%24%E9%5D%A8H%9B%17x%1F%1C%DC%BD%7B%1C%3F%FEw%F7%86%F7%09fF%BB%88(%96Ev%1D%06%95%82%3A%25%A5%7C%DE%BE%16m%B0%20%C10%B8X%B2%00%00g%18%B0%9D%C6%11%22r%FAM%9C%BA5%85z%BD%0E%D7u%11%8F%C7w%04%13%04%01%B4%D6H%A7%D3X%BE%BE%1C9%EF%066%84%80Bh%BAg%AE%1D%C1%87%8F%3F%E1%FB%BE%94R%BE%DD%8D%14%89H%DC%B9%7De%E3s%3D%40%E5%E6%AB%F0%A4%C3%C0%B3K%13%B8%F7%E0%A5%18%D4%EB%AF%96g%F6%3D%A9~%FAr%F7%F2%8B%D0%DF%90%3B%8F%E9%E2qff%0C%FAx%F6%E8%BC%7B%A80%FE%BA%D7%B7%E5%FB%DD%9F%195%E2'%3B%7D%F6%BEN%26c%FD%13.%95J%AC%94J%9A%9003C)%B5%A7X%2C%AEF%26%DCh4%20%A5%FCn%CAR%26%A5%FC%CD%CC%99%CE%B1.%F0N-%5B%FFS%BD%26%07CV%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16%BC-p%10%04%C6%01%7BM%5D%60%CF%F3%40D%C7L%C1%12%91%F0%3C%AFkl%CBvk%EEB%0E%B5ZM%98%00%CE%E7%F3%BC%E2%AF%F4%FF%86%C72%09T%CB3%A3%06%A4%7Bq%2C%93%08%B9%D3%B3%FF%0A%05.%1C%1E%7F%3A%C0%1D%CBsJ%A9%83%B3%D3%13%1Cf%8Bl%19%1C%BDT%80%FE%B1%0E%DF%F7G%A4%94%AD%5DJ%15%8F%1F%5E%E57%EF%BEE%B7%0C%E6%B8%E5-R%ECk%D4C%26%E7'%D7%9A%CDf%E2_%9A2Zk%00%80%EB%BA%DB%5E%09%B4%D6H%A5Rk%95%F9J%22j%DE%9Cle%053%0FE%DBk%13%BC%D7%D9%3C%89%0F%016%BD%00%E7%D7%DFN(%11%9D%2C%CB%03%B9E%8A-%19%06%3D%01%E0%FD%02%9CU%00%F83%00%A9%3A%10%0E%94%7F%B9%99%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82",
                            "data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%2C%00%00%00%2C%08%06%00%00%00%1E%84Z%01%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%12%00%00%0B%12%01%D2%DD~%FC%00%00%0AOiCCPPhotoshop%20ICC%20profile%00%00x%DA%9DSgTS%E9%16%3D%F7%DE%F4BK%88%80%94KoR%15%08%20RB%8B%80%14%91%26*!%09%10J%88!%A1%D9%15Q%C1%11EE%04%1B%C8%A0%88%03%8E%8E%80%8C%15Q%2C%0C%8A%0A%D8%07%E4!%A2%8E%83%A3%88%8A%CA%FB%E1%7B%A3k%D6%BC%F7%E6%CD%FE%B5%D7%3E%E7%AC%F3%9D%B3%CF%07%C0%08%0C%96H3Q5%80%0C%A9B%1E%11%E0%83%C7%C4%C6%E1%E4.%40%81%0A%24p%00%10%08%B3d!s%FD%23%01%00%F8~%3C%3C%2B%22%C0%07%BE%00%01x%D3%0B%08%00%C0M%9B%C00%1C%87%FF%0F%EAB%99%5C%01%80%84%01%C0t%918K%08%80%14%00%40z%8EB%A6%00%40F%01%80%9D%98%26S%00%A0%04%00%60%CBcb%E3%00P-%00%60'%7F%E6%D3%00%80%9D%F8%99%7B%01%00%5B%94!%15%01%A0%91%00%20%13e%88D%00h%3B%00%AC%CFV%8AE%00X0%00%14fK%C49%00%D8-%000IWfH%00%B0%B7%00%C0%CE%10%0B%B2%00%08%0C%000Q%88%85)%00%04%7B%00%60%C8%23%23x%00%84%99%00%14F%F2W%3C%F1%2B%AE%10%E7*%00%00x%99%B2%3C%B9%249E%81%5B%08-q%07WW.%1E(%CEI%17%2B%146a%02a%9A%40.%C2y%99%192%814%0F%E0%F3%CC%00%00%A0%91%15%11%E0%83%F3%FDx%CE%0E%AE%CE%CE6%8E%B6%0E_-%EA%BF%06%FF%22bb%E3%FE%E5%CF%ABp%40%00%00%E1t~%D1%FE%2C%2F%B3%1A%80%3B%06%80m%FE%A2%25%EE%04h%5E%0B%A0u%F7%8Bf%B2%0F%40%B5%00%A0%E9%DAW%F3p%F8~%3C%3CE%A1%90%B9%D9%D9%E5%E4%E4%D8J%C4B%5Ba%CAW%7D%FEg%C2_%C0W%FDl%F9~%3C%FC%F7%F5%E0%BE%E2%24%812%5D%81G%04%F8%E0%C2%CC%F4L%A5%1C%CF%92%09%84b%DC%E6%8FG%FC%B7%0B%FF%FC%1D%D3%22%C4Ib%B9X*%14%E3Q%12q%8ED%9A%8C%F32%A5%22%89B%92)%C5%25%D2%FFd%E2%DF%2C%FB%03%3E%DF5%00%B0j%3E%01%7B%91-%A8%5Dc%03%F6K'%10Xt%C0%E2%F7%00%00%F2%BBo%C1%D4(%08%03%80h%83%E1%CFw%FF%EF%3F%FDG%A0%25%00%80fI%92q%00%00%5ED%24.T%CA%B3%3F%C7%08%00%00D%A0%81*%B0A%1B%F4%C1%18%2C%C0%06%1C%C1%05%DC%C1%0B%FC%606%84B%24%C4%C2B%10B%0Ad%80%1Cr%60)%AC%82B(%86%CD%B0%1D*%60%2F%D4%40%1D4%C0Qh%86%93p%0E.%C2U%B8%0E%3Dp%0F%FAa%08%9E%C1(%BC%81%09%04A%C8%08%13a!%DA%88%01b%8AX%23%8E%08%17%99%85%F8!%C1H%04%12%8B%24%20%C9%88%14Q%22K%915H1R%8AT%20UH%1D%F2%3Dr%029%87%5CF%BA%91%3B%C8%002%82%FC%86%BCG1%94%81%B2Q%3D%D4%0C%B5C%B9%A87%1A%84F%A2%0B%D0dt1%9A%8F%16%A0%9B%D0r%B4%1A%3D%8C6%A1%E7%D0%ABh%0F%DA%8F%3EC%C70%C0%E8%18%073%C4l0.%C6%C3B%B18%2C%09%93c%CB%B1%22%AC%0C%AB%C6%1A%B0V%AC%03%BB%89%F5c%CF%B1w%04%12%81E%C0%096%04wB%20a%1EAHXLXN%D8H%A8%20%1C%244%11%DA%097%09%03%84Q%C2'%22%93%A8K%B4%26%BA%11%F9%C4%18b21%87XH%2C%23%D6%12%8F%13%2F%10%7B%88C%C47%24%12%89C2'%B9%90%02I%B1%A4T%D2%12%D2F%D2nR%23%E9%2C%A9%9B4H%1A%23%93%C9%DAdk%B2%079%94%2C%20%2B%C8%85%E4%9D%E4%C3%E43%E4%1B%E4!%F2%5B%0A%9Db%40q%A4%F8S%E2(R%CAjJ%19%E5%10%E54%E5%06e%982AU%A3%9AR%DD%A8%A1T%115%8FZB%AD%A1%B6R%AFQ%87%A8%134u%9A9%CD%83%16IK%A5%AD%A2%95%D3%1Ah%17h%F7i%AF%E8t%BA%11%DD%95%1EN%97%D0W%D2%CB%E9G%E8%97%E8%03%F4w%0C%0D%86%15%83%C7%88g(%19%9B%18%07%18g%19w%18%AF%98L%A6%19%D3%8B%19%C7T071%EB%98%E7%99%0F%99oUX*%B6*%7C%15%91%CA%0A%95J%95%26%95%1B*%2FT%A9%AA%A6%AA%DE%AA%0BU%F3U%CBT%8F%A9%5ES%7D%AEFU3S%E3%A9%09%D4%96%ABU%AA%9DP%EBS%1BSg%A9%3B%A8%87%AAg%A8oT%3F%A4~Y%FD%89%06Y%C3L%C3OC%A4Q%A0%B1_%E3%BC%C6%20%0Bc%19%B3x%2C!k%0D%AB%86u%815%C4%26%B1%CD%D9%7Cv*%BB%98%FD%1D%BB%8B%3D%AA%A9%A19C3J3W%B3R%F3%94f%3F%07%E3%98q%F8%9CtN%09%E7(%A7%97%F3~%8A%DE%14%EF)%E2)%1B%A64L%B91e%5Ck%AA%96%97%96X%ABH%ABQ%ABG%EB%BD6%AE%ED%A7%9D%A6%BDE%BBY%FB%81%0EA%C7J'%5C'Gg%8F%CE%05%9D%E7S%D9S%DD%A7%0A%A7%16M%3D%3A%F5%AE.%AAk%A5%1B%A1%BBDw%BFn%A7%EE%98%9E%BE%5E%80%9ELo%A7%DEy%BD%E7%FA%1C%7D%2F%FDT%FDm%FA%A7%F5G%0CX%06%B3%0C%24%06%DB%0C%CE%18%3C%C55qo%3C%1D%2F%C7%DB%F1QC%5D%C3%40C%A5a%95a%97%E1%84%91%B9%D1%3C%A3%D5F%8DF%0F%8Ci%C6%5C%E3%24%E3m%C6m%C6%A3%26%06%26!%26KM%EAM%EE%9ARM%B9%A6)%A6%3BL%3BL%C7%CD%CC%CD%A2%CD%D6%995%9B%3D1%D72%E7%9B%E7%9B%D7%9B%DF%B7%60ZxZ%2C%B6%A8%B6%B8eI%B2%E4Z%A6Y%EE%B6%BCn%85Z9Y%A5XUZ%5D%B3F%AD%9D%AD%25%D6%BB%AD%BB%A7%11%A7%B9N%93N%AB%9E%D6g%C3%B0%F1%B6%C9%B6%A9%B7%19%B0%E5%D8%06%DB%AE%B6m%B6%7Dagb%17g%B7%C5%AE%C3%EE%93%BD%93%7D%BA%7D%8D%FD%3D%07%0D%87%D9%0E%AB%1DZ%1D~s%B4r%14%3AV%3A%DE%9A%CE%9C%EE%3F%7D%C5%F4%96%E9%2FgX%CF%10%CF%D83%E3%B6%13%CB)%C4i%9DS%9B%D3Gg%17g%B9s%83%F3%88%8B%89K%82%CB.%97%3E.%9B%1B%C6%DD%C8%BD%E4Jt%F5q%5D%E1z%D2%F5%9D%9B%B3%9B%C2%ED%A8%DB%AF%EE6%EEi%EE%87%DC%9F%CC4%9F)%9EY3s%D0%C3%C8C%E0Q%E5%D1%3F%0B%9F%950k%DF%AC~OCO%81g%B5%E7%23%2Fc%2F%91W%AD%D7%B0%B7%A5w%AA%F7a%EF%17%3E%F6%3Er%9F%E3%3E%E3%3C7%DE2%DEY_%CC7%C0%B7%C8%B7%CBO%C3o%9E_%85%DFC%7F%23%FFd%FFz%FF%D1%00%A7%80%25%01g%03%89%81A%81%5B%02%FB%F8z%7C!%BF%8E%3F%3A%DBe%F6%B2%D9%EDA%8C%A0%B9A%15A%8F%82%AD%82%E5%C1%AD!h%C8%EC%90%AD!%F7%E7%98%CE%91%CEi%0E%85P~%E8%D6%D0%07a%E6a%8B%C3~%0C'%85%87%85W%86%3F%8Ep%88X%1A%D11%975w%D1%DCCs%DFD%FAD%96D%DE%9Bg1O9%AF-J5*%3E%AA.j%3C%DA7%BA4%BA%3F%C6.fY%CC%D5X%9DXIlK%1C9.*%AE6nl%BE%DF%FC%ED%F3%87%E2%9D%E2%0B%E3%7B%17%98%2F%C8%5Dpy%A1%CE%C2%F4%85%A7%16%A9.%12%2C%3A%96%40L%88N8%94%F0A%10*%A8%16%8C%25%F2%13w%25%8E%0Ay%C2%1D%C2g%22%2F%D16%D1%88%D8C%5C*%1EN%F2H*Mz%92%EC%91%BC5y%24%C53%A5%2C%E5%B9%84'%A9%90%BCL%0DL%DD%9B%3A%9E%16%9Av%20m2%3D%3A%BD1%83%92%91%90qB%AA!M%93%B6g%EAg%E6fv%CB%ACe%85%B2%FE%C5n%8B%B7%2F%1E%95%07%C9k%B3%90%AC%05Y-%0A%B6B%A6%E8TZ(%D7*%07%B2geWf%BF%CD%89%CA9%96%AB%9E%2B%CD%ED%CC%B3%CA%DB%907%9C%EF%9F%FF%ED%12%C2%12%E1%92%B6%A5%86KW-%1DX%E6%BD%ACj9%B2%3Cqy%DB%0A%E3%15%05%2B%86V%06%AC%3C%B8%8A%B6*m%D5O%AB%EDW%97%AE~%BD%26zMk%81%5E%C1%CA%82%C1%B5%01k%EB%0BU%0A%E5%85%7D%EB%DC%D7%ED%5DOX%2FY%DF%B5a%FA%86%9D%1B%3E%15%89%8A%AE%14%DB%17%97%15%7F%D8(%DCx%E5%1B%87o%CA%BF%99%DC%94%B4%A9%AB%C4%B9d%CFf%D2f%E9%E6%DE-%9E%5B%0E%96%AA%97%E6%97%0En%0D%D9%DA%B4%0D%DFV%B4%ED%F5%F6E%DB%2F%97%CD(%DB%BB%83%B6C%B9%A3%BF%3C%B8%BCe%A7%C9%CE%CD%3B%3FT%A4T%F4T%FAT6%EE%D2%DD%B5a%D7%F8n%D1%EE%1B%7B%BC%F64%EC%D5%DB%5B%BC%F7%FD%3E%C9%BE%DBU%01UM%D5f%D5e%FBI%FB%B3%F7%3F%AE%89%AA%E9%F8%96%FBm%5D%ADNmq%ED%C7%03%D2%03%FD%07%23%0E%B6%D7%B9%D4%D5%1D%D2%3DTR%8F%D6%2B%EBG%0E%C7%1F%BE%FE%9D%EFw-%0D6%0DU%8D%9C%C6%E2%23pDy%E4%E9%F7%09%DF%F7%1E%0D%3A%DAv%8C%7B%AC%E1%07%D3%1Fv%1Dg%1D%2FjB%9A%F2%9AF%9BS%9A%FB%5Bb%5B%BAO%CC%3E%D1%D6%EA%DEz%FCG%DB%1F%0F%9C4%3CYyJ%F3T%C9i%DA%E9%82%D3%93g%F2%CF%8C%9D%95%9D%7D~.%F9%DC%60%DB%A2%B6%7B%E7c%CE%DFj%0Fo%EF%BA%10t%E1%D2E%FF%8B%E7%3B%BC%3B%CE%5C%F2%B8t%F2%B2%DB%E5%13W%B8W%9A%AF%3A_m%EAt%EA%3C%FE%93%D3O%C7%BB%9C%BB%9A%AE%B9%5Ck%B9%EEz%BD%B5%7Bf%F7%E9%1B%9E7%CE%DD%F4%BDy%F1%16%FF%D6%D5%9E9%3D%DD%BD%F3zo%F7%C5%F7%F5%DF%16%DD~r'%FD%CE%CB%BB%D9w'%EE%AD%BCO%BC_%F4%40%EDA%D9C%DD%87%D5%3F%5B%FE%DC%D8%EF%DC%7Fj%C0w%A0%F3%D1%DCG%F7%06%85%83%CF%FE%91%F5%8F%0FC%05%8F%99%8F%CB%86%0D%86%EB%9E8%3E99%E2%3Fr%FD%E9%FC%A7C%CFd%CF%26%9E%17%FE%A2%FE%CB%AE%17%16%2F~%F8%D5%EB%D7%CE%D1%98%D1%A1%97%F2%97%93%BFm%7C%A5%FD%EA%C0%EB%19%AF%DB%C6%C2%C6%1E%BE%C9x31%5E%F4V%FB%ED%C1w%DCw%1D%EF%A3%DF%0FO%E4%7C%20%7F(%FFh%F9%B1%F5S%D0%A7%FB%93%19%93%93%FF%04%03%98%F3%FCc3-%DB%00%00%00%20cHRM%00%00z%25%00%00%80%83%00%00%F9%FF%00%00%80%E9%00%00u0%00%00%EA%60%00%00%3A%98%00%00%17o%92_%C5F%00%00%01%E1IDATx%DA%EC%D9AK%1BA%14%07%F0%FF%245)a%13%16%E3%B1%11%EF%AE%BD%0C%12%05%DB%AA(%BD(Hb%A9%06%15%82%20%F8%0D%F4%B2%A2_%A5%87%86%B6%5E%3C%E9G%F0%FC%E6%13%F4%1E%1A%D2AXd%7D%1E4e%B3f5E%A2%13%98%81%07%BB%B3s%F8%ED%EC%DB9%BC%07fF'%88(%CD%00%9B%14D%B4%1C5%0Af%06%00%40%88%FB%0BC%07%B3%00%80%D4P%60%23%C67J%A9%94%F7%C8%BA%CD%8D%0D4%9BM8%8E%83l6%3B%10K%10%04%D0Z%A3X%2C%E2%7B%A3%91%B8%EE%087%02I%B9%B3%B6%3A%C7RJ%26%A2%C9h%0E%0D2%88H%EC%EF.qu%EDCbN%F7%04%EF%D4%E6%F9%A5%90%BD%E2%FC%C7%D6%D8%FE%EER%7F%E0Ze%F1U%B1%11%B43S%9E%BE%8C%FBR%F1%3CyW%CA%18%F1%8F%7D%FE%F2M%E7%F3%E9%1E%A7ED_%AF%D7%99%88%F2%26%EC%F0%7DN%8FT*%95%DF%89%3B%DCj%B5%E0y%DE_SN2%CF%F3%AE%99%B9%14%9D%EB%02%0F%EA%D8z%CE%88%9BR%18%B2a%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%16l%C1%7D%81%83%200%0E%187u%81%5D%D7%85Rj%C1%14%ACRJ%B8%AE%DB%3D%19%AF%0EJ)%D9%94%DA%9A%94%92%9F%AC%5EN%94r%B8%F8%B9%9D1%60w%F7%26J%B9%87%0Fz%15%8D%CB%B3%D3g%AFX%B1%FCJD%EFwj%F3%FDW%E0%19%E0O%1F%CB%9D%96A%FA%05%B189%5Cy%B4e%20%7C%0E%DDc%91%FE%93%F4i%D6%AB%D5%ABv%BB%9D%FB%9F%A6%8C%D6%1A%00%E08N%DF'%81%D6%1A%85B%E1%EA%D7%E9i.i%DD%11%87SwogX31)%7C%0E%DF%82%99%E1s%98%19%02%EC(%DF%DD%FD%CB%9Fe%9F%C3%03%03%A1%8B%3E%87%E3%1D%E7%ED%00%867%F9%C7%AF%EF%A2%93%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82",
                            "data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%2C%00%00%00%2C%08%06%00%00%00%1E%84Z%01%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00%06bKGD%00%FF%00%FF%00%FF%A0%BD%A7%93%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%13%00%00%0B%13%01%00%9A%9C%18%00%00%00%07tIME%07%D9%0A%18%10%1A2B%24%88%BD%00%00%00%19tEXtComment%00Created%20with%20GIMPW%81%0E%17%00%00%05cIDATX%C3%ED%99%DBoTU%14%87%BF%7Dn%D3%B9%D6%C3%14a%2CJ%AD%A2E%05%12%C6%A8%01%EA%25%01%04%A1%801%D5%98%98xK%1A%13%FF%80%F2%17%18%EA%8B%064%81%C6%175%A61U%92a%8C1f%D4p%8D!%14%02%82m!%0E-%DA%22%ED%B4%A7%5CJ%3B%E7%EA%C3%CC%F4b%81%E9%83%C2%A9%F1%F7t%F6%D9%FB%E4%7CYY%7B%ED%BD%D6%12L%D1%85%FD%09%5D%D1%22%B5%C0Z%A0%11%A8%05tn%A0%F4%818%FB%0E%C4)%A7-%CF%0C%D1P%3FTv%5D%EA%D0%7C%D2G%AA%08j%AE%A1%A9nVU%BC%F6P%C0%CD%C8%C2%CC~%BC%FB'%A3%B4N%94%1E%FA%0E%D7%D4%0AIm%04%9A%8A%A07%D5la%B7%3D%9Bc%D3%9A%E1Y%C1%A6%0E%CD%BF%D1T%16h%05%DA%BFK%A5%B2%13%C0E%D8%E6%A2Uu%00%25T%87%1C%A8F%A9%B8%0F!%02x%9E%85%E7%8E%F1%CD%0F9%D2%99%5Cy%D8%E7%E7%B3i%DD%C3%B7%5C%E3Z9R%3F%0D%B3o%D2%80%D8%B6%8D%E38%D8%A6Yze%D4%2F%1Fi%7F%7DCo%CB%A2%D5%3DYQt%83%26%A0%19%D0%95%8AZ%D4h%12%F3%F2%01%BA%BB%BB%F9v%FF8%7D%97%1C%EE%8AJ%FC%3E%10%A3%B3'Z%16%F6%B1%DA%2B%2C%B9%EFZ%D9u%9D%BDQ~%ED%89a%DB6%96e%11%0C%06YP%5DMee%25ZE%05f%3E%CF%AAGs%BC%B1%B1%DF%10%D0b%9B%D7Z%95%A2%CF6%96%60%B5%CAU%7C%F1%E9%07%FCr%D6%EA8%7B%DE%DEn%D9%5E%C7%C1cf%D1%04%E5!%00%BA%BB%99%A5%AE%02%FD%13%A3y%F1%B8%AEhZS_ooc%24%16K%BE%FD%DAS%BC%FA%DC5%9Cqt%A0Q%D1%22%19%A9%B8%C1%92%00jd%05_%B5%7DH%DF%25%A7ew%DB%E8%E3%3F%FE%9C%CFL%C2%FE%FB%1A%1E%1A2%3AO%9DjY%B2t%E9%BA%9A%05%23%AD%91%B16%B4%C8%8A%D2t%12X%5B%02F%D6%12%B8%F6%08g%CEY%D9%F7v_%DD%CE%1D%D4%F7%E9%B4%F1%D1%F6%B1%ED'%BB%AC%0E%D7%1EA%D6%12%A5%A9%B5%D2%A4u%97q%F4%F0%5E%96%DC%AF%B6%E3%03-~%E6%A2%11%0D%8B%D6%A3%87%F7%A2F%96MXY*%3DIj%15'%3A-%DA%D2%A3-%F8D%07%8F%E5%DBOtZHj%D5%C4%BB%09%60!%05%B98%E0p%3B%7D%B6%3C%B0i%5C%1Cp%10R%B0%10%06%3DP%A6DE%C2!%81%DF%14%0E%09%84%1C%C6%B4%05m%99%85S%81%A1%AB'Z%0C5%FE%92i%B9%EC%FA%FA%5E%06%0Dm%D2%25%D2%99K%B3%3A%14n%B7%1CW%B0%F3%F3%B3%9C9%1FAS%3D%14%40O%1F%88%F3%E3%F1%3F%F1%A3%8E%9C%8E%93%18%BFR%1A%EA%D2l%2F2wJ%03F%60%DAX%F23%EC%8D%24%CD%25XEv%E7%16%B0%AAxs%0Bx%CE%B9%C4%0C%60I%F2%7C%0B*%04%D4%2F%1F%99%04V%15%89'%1E1%7C%0B%FB%C6%C6~%D6%94%80%15%D9%E3%9D%D7%EBHT%8D%FB%0F%16x%F3%A5%87%A8_%3ER%F0%02E%F6x%F7%E5~%96%2F%9D%E7K%EB%AE%7C%D8%60%CD%CA%BB%26%DD%F6%DD%97%FBy%EC%81Q%DF%FAn%CD%C2%EB%D37%9D%9Fa%E7lX%13R%E0%3F%12%87%FF%07%FE%87%E4%B9%F9%B9i%E1c%5D%B1%E9%C0%9D%BDQ%DF%C2vt%C7%D8%B3%AFz%128%F5C%1F%BF%F6%C4%FC%09%7Bz%98%3D%FB%AAq%5CQ%C8%9AS%87%E6%939%F9%87%2Fa%FBrA%F6%7C%F9%1B%B6S(AHS%8B%C9%B6m%FB%2F%09%3D%15%C5%B2%DD%89%DB%A4T%82%F5%3C%8F%8AP%88y%F1%B8%EE%17%D8xU%5C%D7%82a%3C%AFp%ED%0D%A8S2%0E%C7q%A8%D4u%84%2C'%FD%13t%E5d%A5%AE%E38%CE%B4%B0f%00%D8%A6%C9%82D%82X%2C%B6c%7DC%C3%1D%B7%F2%FA%86%06%3D%16%8B%EDX%90HLk%1F(%40%06ht%1C%07U%08*u%3DYa%1Eo%06%EEH%8D%F8%85m%9Bu%DB%11%9C%3Fw%AE%B9R%D7%93B%88%A9%16%CE%C8%0F%D6%D5A%A1F%AC%7B%9E%C7%5B%AF%2Ceq%EC%D8%9APP%3C%BA%B0J6%16-%94%8D%0B%FD%CE%F8%ED%F2YU%0B%EE%E8%BBp%A19%14%894%3EXW%87%99%CF%E3%B9.%40VU%BC%9Db%7DC%83.IR3%D0%D4%B0zPo%5C%17%BDiS%26%1C%12%8C%E5e%F6%9F%ACbtL%B9%E9%8FM%D3D%00O-%1B%9Dq%9F%BD%91z%FA5%8E%9C%0E%13%08%84f4e%9CB%E42%80%D6%80j%B5%08%80%0D%5B%B7%26%B7%AC%1El%DAV%3F8%B5%EDe(%155%86%1CH%E8B%0A%EBB%0E%92%1B%BE%CA%FB%9Ft28%9C%BF%F5%D9%EF%B9%BC%F9%E2%22%9E~bQY%D8%D3%E7.%B3%F3%B3n%2C%DB%9B%08%AD%7Fo%7B%01%ED%40%EBw%A9T%87%02%B0%E9%C9%3F%B2%DB%EA%AF%94Z%05k%81Z%FBz%97n_%EF%D2%8B%1F%18C%97U%BD%A5%AD%86%DC%88%3A%AB%84q%E5%3DG%B9V%E6%2C%3As%3E%C2%AE%AF%EF%C5%B4oZ%97%CE%16%F7X%BB%EB%BA%93%8DE%98%D1%B6%AD-%FAu-%A0%7B%C0%DE%FDw3%60h%B8%1E%8C%E5%E5%825%1C%81i%15%22%E3%B8)%E1%B8%B0yUn%22a%BC%25lO%B8%00k%CD%B8%7F%19E%D0%8E%12%B0%EB%BA%D9%EF%D3i%03%E0%2F%83C1%CE%13%14%8D%91%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82"
                        ];

    for (J = srchTxtArry.length-1;  J >= 0;  --J)
    {
        var zRegex  = new RegExp (srchTxtArry[J], "i");
        if (zRegex.test (difficultyText) )
        {
            borderElement.style.setProperty ("background", 'url("' + badgeBorderArry[J] + '") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent', "important");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that I had to change one image just so that this answer would be under SO's 30,000 character limit.

Comment: This is so much simpler. I should have gutted the original code and rebuilt it using only one loop, as you did, but was hoping I could throw the proverbial "patch" on and it would work again. I'm not too good with RegEx yet, but I'll prob. get more practice in my Data Structures class next semester. I added comments for myself to make future maintenance easier, and so I could see where my original design was flawed. The userscript URL is in orig. post, and I added you to the credits. Thanks a ton, Brock!